HTTP/2 server reset the stream. HTTP/2 error code 'INTERNAL_ERROR' when enabling stream_options
I was using this reference code to calculate the openai streaming tokens. This was working all good.
var originalStream = await responseContext.ProxyResponse.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

// Buffer for reading chunks
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
int bytesRead;

// Read, inspect, and write the data in chunks - this is especially needed for streaming content
while ((bytesRead = await originalStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    // Convert the chunk to a string for inspection
    var chunk = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

    stringBuilder.Append(chunk);

    // Write the unmodified chunk back to the response
    await responseContext.HttpContext.Response.Body.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}

However when i start using the new feature "stream_options": {"include_usage": true} which might only work for text prompt and not give the usage details for image inputs image_url due to some unknown limitation or a bug. Hence we have to use our own logic above for calculating the usage tokens.
Coming to the main issue. The above code is throwing The HTTP/2 server reset the stream. HTTP/2 error code 'INTERNAL_ERROR' (0x2). (HttpProtocolError)
Error Stack Trace:

Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpProtocolException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
warn: Yarp.ReverseProxy.Forwarder.HttpForwarder[48]
      ResponseHeaders: The destination returned a response that cannot be proxied back to the client.
      System.Net.Http.HttpProtocolException: The HTTP/2 server reset the stream. HTTP/2 error code 'INTERNAL_ERROR' (0x2). (HttpProtocolError)
         at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.ThrowRequestAborted(Exception innerException)
         at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.Http2Stream.CheckResponseBodyState()
         at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.Http2Stream.TryReadFromBuffer(Span`1 buffer, Boolean partOfSyncRead)
         at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.Http2Stream.ReadDataAsync(Memory`1 buffer, HttpResponseMessage responseMessage, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HN7CT37HO2VS", Request id "0HN7CT37HO2VS:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
      System.InvalidOperationException: The response cannot be cleared, it has already started sending.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.ResponseExtensions.Clear(HttpResponse response)
         at Yarp.ReverseProxy.Forwarder.HttpForwarder.SendAsync(HttpContext context, String destinationPrefix, HttpMessageInvoker httpClient, ForwarderRequestConfig requestConfig, HttpTransformer transformer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Yarp.ReverseProxy.Forwarder.ForwarderMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Yarp.ReverseProxy.Health.PassiveHealthCheckMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

How can i fix this ? I have tried increasing the buffer size to 1MB as well no luck .I also dont know why this particular issue coming only if i enable  What may the reason for this issue "stream_options"

That's not reference code, it's part of a reverse proxy in a multi-project repo (that's not even a reference architecture). The snippet itself has nothing to do with OpenAI, it just forwards chunks from server to client while counting them. Your own code suggests you're using YARP's forwarder, not just Kestrel. It's YARP that complains and the reason is probably that streaming uses Server Sent Events, not complete responses

What are you actually trying to do? Create a YARP forwarder for streaming text prompts? What does your own code look like and what does it do? Do you have custom transforms? You should search for the error message in the YARP repository. The error The HTTP/2 server reset the stream. HTTP/2 error code 'INTERNAL_ERROR' (0x2) appears in a gRPC-related repo. Have you created a gRPC proxy?

@PanagiotisKanavos I simply forked and using the same project (Yarp reverse proxy) from my side. I don't have any gPRC related repo. This error is occurring at while ((bytesRead = await originalStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)  Do you have any idea on what might be the root cause of this ?

You can't just copy code from one repo into another. That proxy was created specifically for that specific demo/sample site. OpenAI can use gRPC streaming and is actually preferable to SSEs. If the API you call uses gRPC, your proxy must also support gRPC.

Why are you creating a reverse proxy in the first place?

because tradionally openai will not give the usage token details for streaming apis. Hence we have to intercept via reverse proxy the api and do our own custom logic to calculate the usage token from the streaming api response and also we want to dynamically handle the throttling by different instance/backend. You can find more details from https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-openai-reverse-proxy

@PanagiotisKanavos can you help me here ?
